# Jaxb association of the same class

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm sorry, the title is not very explicit... In my projet model, I have a `Product` entity that can be associated with other products, but I don't know how to annotate it. Currently, I have done that :

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "product")
    @XmlType(propOrder = { "barCode", "productName", "price", "brand", "description", "reviews", "photos", "videos", "associated" })
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class Product {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
        private Long            productId;
        private String          barCode;
        private String          productName;
        private Double          price;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "photos")
        @XmlElement(name = "photo", type = String.class)
        private List<String>    photos;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "videos")
        @XmlElement(name = "video", type = String.class)
        private List<String>    videos;

        private String          brand;
        private String          description;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "reviews")
        @XmlElement(name = "review", type = Review.class)
        private List<Review>    reviews;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "associated")
        @XmlElement(name = "product", type = Product.class)
        private List<Product>   associated;

        // with constructor, getters and setters not annotated
   }
```

Currently, this mapping is not working, because of cyclic references. I would like to have something like :

```
<product id="1">
   <barCode>123456789</barCode>
   <productName>Product 1</productName>
   <price>100.0</price>
   <brand>Brand 1</brand>
   <description>Description 1</description>
   <reviews/>
   <photos/>
   <videos/>
   <associated>
      <product id="2">
         <barCode>987654321</barCode>
         <productName>Product 2</productName>
         <price>500.0</price>
         <brand>Brand 2</brand>
         <description>Description 2</description>
      </product>
   </associated>
</product>
```

I mean not have in the mapping `photos`, `videos`, `reviews` and `associated`, is it possible?
I hope I was clear enought, if wasn't just ask, I'll explain more in detail !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude mapped fields, use @XmlTransient (good for handling cyclic references)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will no longer be included in the root element, I would only remove it from the `associated` field, not others...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem then

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I'm not very clear... 
I want to generate an XML file like the example, I mean a product, and its associated products. But currently, because of the `associated` field, there are cyclic references, and I don't know how to do that. Am I more understandable?

Comment: You are going to have to use @XmlTransient on `associated` field. That will exclude it from the XML. It's not possible to map cyclic references. There are ways to rebuild the objects once it has been unmarshalled using `afterUnmarshal()` or you can check out MOXy's @XmlInverseReference (although I've never had luck with these 2 approaches)

Comment: Ok I see, I thought it was possible... In last resort, I will use a list of identifier. I can't do the `afterUnmarshal()` because it is for a RESTful web service, with a mobile client.
I've already checked @XmlInverseReference, but I don't think it can apply to this case ! Thanks for your help!